# findAll returns empty list

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

This is Repository interface

```java
@Repository
    public interface MenuStructureTblService extends JpaRepository<MenuStructureTbl, Integer> {
}
```

MenuStructureTbl Table

```java
@Data
@Entity(name = "menu_structure_tbl")
public class MenuStructureTbl {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer menuId;
    public String menuTitle;
    public String menuText;
    public Integer menuMotherId;
    public String createDate;
    public String updateDate;
}
```

I am banging my head on the wall, Returned list is empty.

This one returns null

```java
@Repository
public interface MenuStructureTblService extends JpaRepository<MenuStructureTbl, Integer> {
    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM menu_structure_tbl", nativeQuery = true)
    Object justGetIT();
}
```

Returns null; I have checked the query, generates result. But, I do not know what is going on.

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: What is your expected result? Do you have some rows in your table and they're not found by findAll?

Comment: @RolandWeisleder, I have data

Comment: Are using *findAll()* and gets empty list or you not getting a record for *justGetIT()* you may change the return type from Object to MenuStructureTbl for justGetIT method

Comment: Maybe related: Try to change `@Entity(name = "menu_structure_tbl")` to `@Entity @Table(name = "menu_structure_tbl")`.

Comment: I have tried that too. @Roland it didn't work. I did not mention either.

Comment: Did you run SELECT * FROM menu_structure_tbl in a SQL editor? And did you get results?

Comment: did u try changing return type to `List<MenuStructureTbl>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake, Conflict of Environment, i was checking against wrong environment.